# Find all nodes near the middle of the tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I got this question from my friend's interview: Given a binary tree, print the array of nodes(at most two nodes) from all levels that near the middle of the tree. Here is an example:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3 
 / \   \
4   5   9
       /
      10
```

The output is `[ [2,3], [5,9], [10] ]`.
 I can only think of an inefficient method: level order the tree, for each level, put all nodes in current level into an array, if the node is `NULL`, put a flag(maybe -1 or sth else) into the slot. At the end, print out all nodes in the middle of each array.
 For the above example, my code will first get 4 arrays:
 `[1], [2,3], [4,5,-1,9],[-1,-1,10,-1]`, after this process, print out all middle values in the array which is not -1.
I believe there must exist better solutions, can anybody provide? Thanks!

Comment: Let me ask, if the node 10 is the right child of 9, would the answer for the 4th row still be 10? Because I don't get why you have to put -1 into the arrays.

Comment: @WorakarnIsaratham I'm sorry I made a mistake, it should still be [ [2,3], [5,9], [10] ] if 10 is the right child of 9. The reason I put -1 is just for mark the empty node, I can put * or any other thing to mark the slot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in-order traversal the tree and also keep the node's level

Node:  4-2-5-1-3-10-9

Level: 2-1-2-0-1-3-2

Now for the level output, we start from level 0, find left side first occurrence of 1 -- the corresponding number is 2, find the right side first occurrence of 1 -- the corresponding number is 3, so the level 1 output is <2,3>

do the same thing for level 2 output is <5,9>

for level 3 output is just<10>

Time complexity O(n)
Space complexity O(n)

Same as level order traversal solution

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of for this question is, from the root, we can divide the nodes into two type : **left** side of the root and **right** side of the root. And for each level, for the left side nodes, we find the **right most node**, and for the right side, we find the **left most node**. Hope this will help you!

Comment: You are right, I split in in two parts, then level order each subtree, however, I think if so, the time complexity will be same, space complexity may be improved.

Answer (score 0):

We can never be sure if an element exists in an ith level until we've traversed all the elements of the tree. Hence, the time complexity can never be optimised better than O(n), which is the same as the algorithm proposed by you.

The only problem in your solution is that for each level a seperate array is required to be maintained. Though asymptotically the space complexity remains the same, in absolute numbers it becomes extra usage.

What you can do is the following:

1. Do level order traversal.
2. For each element when you're pushing it to the queue (for level order traversal), also maintain the deviation of the element from the middle. The root will be having deviation as 0. The root's left child will be having -1. whereas the right child will be +1.
3. For each level, you'll need to keep a "global" element(s) on how close an element is to the middle. For a given level, there can be at max 2 elements only.
4. Continue this for every level.

This algorithm works better space complexity wise for sparse trees.

Hope this helps!